# What is better way represent a spatial data

Tags: database, algorithm, spatial, kdtree

I have the following problem in my system :
my system is client-server architectural . my application is about recognition building in a city .so i decide to separate the map of the city into grids each grid has an area equal 30 x 30 m . for each grid region i store the center point of the grid (lat,long) . **so my question is if a user is located in a specific grid x 
it's location are send to the server how i can decide in which grid the user are located ?**

Here's a photo clarify the problem:

[image: City organization as grids]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your grids are all exactly the same size, and are arranged in a perfect rectangle, as indicated by your image. How about storing all grids in a simple 2D array? You can then find the index of any grid by doing

```
grid_size = 30; 
index_x = math.floor(user.x/grid_size); 
index_y = math.floor(user.y/grid_size);
```

Comment: thanks Kevin wonderful  trick ,how about if the situation is mess i.e the grids aren't Close proximity . i think i need to use the kd-tree in this situation right ? do you have another opinion?

Comment: Yeah, kd-tree is probably appropriate when grids aren't nicely aligned.

Comment: Thanks Kevin , one more question  does the gps data need pre-processing (i.e quantize the lat & long ) to <x,y> values or the original values ok ? –

Comment: For kd trees, no processing should be necessary. For a 2d array, the coordinates should be translated so that the top left corner of the top left grid is (0,0).